# Accessing 3rd party app files in iCloud from Windows

Tags: ipad, data-synchronization, icloud

Very closely related to this question: [Are files saved to iCloud via 3rd party applications accessible from icloud.com web interface through browser?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33328/are-files-saved-to-icloud-via-3rd-party-applications-accessible-from-icloud-com)

Is there any way to access files stored by 3rd party apps in iCloud from a  Windows PC?

In my specific case, I use IAWriter on the iPad, and love the automatic syncing feature it providers through iCloud. However, I can't seem to be able to access the synchronized files anywhere else - at least not through the web interface.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one is able to access 3rd party app data via www.iCloud.com. You may have a couple options despite that, the first being to get a Mac. Honestly, that's probably not very practical for you. Otherwise, IAWriter, may have a way to log into your account there and access files - a feature not uncommon with apps like that. If neither of those options work, then you will probably have to wait until they put out an app for Windows (which may not be very high on their list if it is on it at all.

Comment: Thanks! Funnily enough, I *did* get a new Mac recently. However, I can't seem to be able to access the raw iCloud data even there. Do you know how this is done?